# High CPU consumption MySQL - db 500k record wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, easy-engine

anyone has or has had this problem with queries in mysql sleep with time above 200 and also opens 100 sleep queries

http://prntscr.com/k7hliy
http://prntscr.com/k7hm15

my site is wordpress and I am having mysql perfomance problem consuming lots of cpu
http://prntscr.com/k7k3uo
http://prntscr.com/k7hmoj

I currently use easyengine + redis cache / server 32gb ram xeon
is a news portal with more than 500 thousand posts

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: Share more relevant information such as Redis and server config. For a possible relevance to the context.

Comment: Is there a reason to have more than 5 copies of mysqld running according to top?  Each one using resources.

Comment: @debora Rodrigues  Please post text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%' ; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; since more than 100 threads are involved in your top information provided.